# Every button getting loaded on clicking single button in Nuxt vuetify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

When I am clicking on View Button every button is getting spinned. Here is the code which I used to view payload. Though I am getting correct data after clicking button, button I want to know reasons why every button is getting loaded though I have clicked on only one View.

Here are the screenshots
[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZlK1.png)
[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdJNL.png)

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="tasks"
      class="elevation-1"
      :loading="loading"
      hide-actions
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.reason }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.requestedBy.adminName }}</td>
        <td>{{ new Date(props.item.createdAt).toLocaleString("en") }}</td>
        <td class="layout px-0">
          <v-btn
            small
            :loading="downloadingPayload"
            @click="getPayload(props.item._id)"
          >
            View
          </v-btn>
        </td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Comment: can you post getPayload function ?

Comment: @4061-Yogeshwaran, here it is  getPayload(id) {
      this.payload = null;
      this.downloadingPayload = true;
      this.$axios
        .$get(`/task?_id=${id}`, { headers: { Authorization: this.token } })
        .then(response => {
          console.log("[Tasks View] Got payload", response.data);
          const { data } = response;
          this.payload = data.docs[0].payload;
          this.dialog = true;
          this.downloadingPayload = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.downloadingPayload = false;
        });
    }

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have the same data for all the elements.

```
:loading="downloadingPayload"
```

i guess you have something like this in your method

```
getPayload (item) { this.downloadingPayload = true  }
```

need to have a `downloadingPayload` for each item and do something like

```
getPayload (item) {
   item.downloadingPayload = true
}
```

and in the template

```
:loading="props.item.downloadingPayload"
```